# Alignment and Two Line Horizontal scrollable in UICollectionView Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am new here, actually I haven't found an answer that how to setup two line horizontal collectionView Items. I have already created tag items CollectionView and as a one row it works perfectly fine. But I want to divide it into two rows but it also horizontally scroll. I am using collectionView inside of tableview for sections.

tag items width based on text.

I have found one library [TTGTagCollectionView](https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGTagCollectionView) but that's in objective C.

**Updated Image attached if I increase height of collectionView it gives extra spacing and alignment issues. Image attached.**

Please anyone guide me about it. How can I resolve this?
Below my code

```
class TagTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var Data = ["AutoLayout","A","Roman","List of Collections","calculates","Grid","TableView","CollectionView","B","view","Apple","IPhone"]
    
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

func setup() {
collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "TagCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TagCollectionViewCell")
let collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(collectionFlowLayout, animated: true)
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
            collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
            collectionFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
        }
    
}

extension TagTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Data.count
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TagCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TagCollectionViewCell
        let dic = Data[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl?.text = dic
        cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        return cell
    }
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let dic = Data[indexPath.row]
        return CGSize(width: self.estimatedFrame(text: dic, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.thin)), height: 50)
    }
    
func estimatedFrame(text: String, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 0.0)
let boundingBox = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                                   options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                                   attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font],
                                                   context: nil)
return boundingBox.size.width + 20.0
}
}
```

tableCell, result images and last image from TTGTagCollectionView
[tablecell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCGFZ.png)

[Myresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3LiC.png)

[TTGTagCollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkAmu.png)

[Extra spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVv2U.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the height of your collection view and it will be in 2 rows.

Comment: Yes I have change the collection view height it comes in two rows but the alignments are disturbed and extra blank spacing coming.

Comment: I have attached updated image `Extra Spacing`